# SQL select and function statements

Tags: sql

OK I made a select statement and its not doing as I hoped, I've tried to tweak it to do as I want it to but it wont work. I'm adding a image of what it looks like with the select I wrote. There's three totals at the bottom of the picture. I want one row with TotalSalary,AvreageSalary, and all player count. Hopefully that makes sense.

```
SELECT DISTINCT  teamID as Team, yearid as 'Year', 
       SUM(salary) AS TotalSalary, AVG(salary) AS AverageSalary,
       Count(playerID) as players
FROM Salaries 
GROUP BY teamID, salary, yearID, playerID 
HAVING teamID = N'SEA' 
   and yearID = N'2010'
```

[image]

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: So everything ok except you need the total?

Comment: Not related to your question, but the word `distinct` is redundant because you have a `group by` clause.

Comment: using SQL server 2016, and yes I'm trying to do one row with all that in it.

Comment: @DanBracuk Incorrect most likely, as `DISTINCT` is usually implemented under the hood using `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUPING SETS`:

```
SELECT teamID as Team,
       yearid as Year, 
       SUM(salary) AS TotalSalary,
       AVG(salary) AS AverageSalary,
       COUNT(playerID) AS players
FROM Salaries 
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS((teamID, yearid), ())
HAVING teamID = N'SEA' AND
       yearID = N'2010'
```

Note that your original query seems confused, because you are mixing `DISTINCT` with `GROUP BY`.

Comment: thank you that was alot of help. and thanks for pointing out the Distinct that actually makes sense didn't even think about it.

Comment: @CJ87 I slightly changed my answer.  I think you should use `GROUPING SETS` here.